# Windows command prompt: how to get the count of all files in current directory?

Tags: powershell, directory, windows-command-prompt, command-line-interface

What command would you use in `cmd.exe` to find the number of files in the current directory?

Is there a powershell option here?

**Update**: I was hoping to avoid `dir`, as I know there are 10,000+ files in the current directory. Wanted to avoid the enumeration output to the cmd window. Thank you!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to do it with `cmd`, then the following is the trivial way to do it:

```
set count=0 & for %x in (*) do @(set /a count+=1 >nul)
echo %count%
```

That's assuming the command line. In a batch file you would do

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set count=0
for %%x in (*) do set /a count+=1
echo %count%
endlocal
```

which does things a little nicer. You can drop the `>nul` in a batch, since `set /a` won't display the result if run from a batch file—it does directly from the command line. Furthermore the `%` sign in the `for` loop has to be doubled.

I've seen quite a few instances where people try nifty tricks with `find /c`. *Be **very** careful with those, as various things can break this.*

Common mistakes:

1. Using `find /c /v` and try finding something that is never included in a file name, such as `::`. Won't. Work. Reliably. When the console window is set to raster fonts then you *can* get those character combination. I can include characters in a file name such as `:`, `?`, etc. in their full-width variants for example, which will then get converted to their normal ASCII counterparts which will break this. If you need an accurate count, then don't try this.
2. Using `find /c` and try finding something that is *always* included in a file name. Obviously the dot (`.`) is a poor choice. Another answer suggests

   ```
   dir /a-d | find /c ":"
   ```

   which assumes several things about the user's locale, not all of which are guaranteed to be true (I've left a comment detailing the problems there) and returns one result too much.

Generally, you want to use `find` on `dir /b` which cuts away all the non-filename stuff and avoids fencepost errors that way.

So the elegant variant would be:

```
dir /b /a-d | find /c /v ""
```

which will first output all file names, one line each. And then count all lines of that output which are not empty. Since the file name can't be empty (unless I'm missing something, but Unicode will not trip this up according to my tests).

Comment: +1 That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you JR!

Comment: Small tweak to make the 1st version all one line:  (set count=0 & for %x in (*) do @(set /a count+=1 >nul)) && echo %count%

Comment: +1 for `dir /b /a-d | find /c /v ""`

Comment: This solution doesn't work well when there are millions of files.  It runs "forever" - a better solution is posted below that runs "in seconds" using PS and [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($path).Count

Comment: @jason, that would probably fail since `%count%` is expanded at parse time.

Comment: @ripvlan: Back then "Windows Command Line" basically meant `cmd`. I can't test right now, but the `for`-based variant shouldn't be needlessly slow.

Comment: @Joey I tried both the cmdline and batch.cmd version of your post on a folder containing 3.2 million files.  It's been running for over 7 minutes and still hasn't completed.  Where-as the PS script took 3 seconds.

Answer (score 18):

Ask and ye shall receive:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692796.aspx

> Counting the Number of Items in a
>   Folder
>
> Well, what do you know: it looks like
>   the sun is finally coming out, which
>   means it’s almost time for us to go.
>   Before we do, however, let’s show you
>   one last little trick with the
>   Get-ChildItem cmdlet. Sometimes you
>   don’t really need to know much about
>   the files in a folder; all you really
>   need to know is how many files (if
>   any) can be found in a particular
>   folder. Here’s how you can quickly
>   count the number of files in a folder:

```
(Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts).Count
```

> What are we doing here? We’re simply
>   using Get-ChildItem to return a
>   collection of all the items found in
>   the folder C:\Scripts; because this is
>   a collection, all we have to do is
>   echo back the value of the Count
>   property, which tells us the number of
>   items in the collection. Note the use
>   of parentheses: we enclose the
>   Get-ChildItem command in parentheses
>   to ensure that Windows PowerShell
>   first grabs the collection and only
>   then echoes back the value of the
>   Count property for that collection.
>
> And sure, you can include a filter
>   when calling Get-ChildItem. Need to
>   know how many .PS1 files are in the
>   folder C:\Scripts? Okey-doke:

```
(Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts -filter "*.ps1").Count
```

FYI .. I googled "powershell count files".

Comment: You need to add a filespec to make the count actually count files, as per the second example

Comment: Just to be clear (Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts).Count will NOT return the number of files in a folder it will return the number of OBJECTS in a folder. You must add a filter or file specification in order to get it to count files. try (gci).count and dir from the root of your C: drive and look at the difference in numbers

Comment: From that same link, if you want to count files in the subfolders too use:
`(Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter "*.ps1").Count`

Comment: Doesn't work if there is exactly one file, have to do something like this: $filecount = @(get-childitem $directory -filter "*.*").Count.  From what I read elsewhere, it's not an array if there is one file.

Comment: @NealWalters: This was correct until PowerShell v3. Since then it doesn't matter.

Comment: This solution doesn't work well when there are millions of files.   It runs "forever" -- look below for a better answer that counts files "in seconds" using [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($path).Count

Answer (score 12):

The fastest method I have found is to run the following in the PS console.

```
[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($path).Count
```

where $path is a local path or UNC share.

Comment: Look at that. A valid awesome answer appeared almost 7.5 years after the question was asked!

Comment: Worked on a Virtual Server in a directory with over 2.1 million files to return the count in about 10 seconds for me.
This should be the correct answer for sure.

Comment: This really is the best answer.  I had a folder with 4.5 million files in it and this method counted them in several seconds.  Methods in other proposed answers ran for several minutes before I gave up on them.

Answer (score 11):

```
dir /a-d | find "File(s)"
```

A word of warning about using PowerShell for simple file operations like this - it is incredibly slow compared to cmd.exe, especially over network connections or when there are thousands of files in the directory. See [this forum post](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/39788-powershell-painfully-slow-across-network.html#post188502) for more info.

Comment: If your system is on a different language than English, you'll have problems with this.

Answer (score 7):

`dir` gives you the total file count at the bottom.

Comment: 1 Up mate, you beat me to this one :)

Comment: and to avoid the cost of watching all the lines scroll through the cmd window... minimize it, it'll work a LOT faster.

Comment: or just `dir > file` .. ahh I miss POSIX

Comment: @lorenz: Any reason why `dir > file` shouldn't work in Windows? Output redirection isn't exactly magic, you know.

Comment: @johannes: it does work, in fact! I miss POSIX because you could "just" do `dir | grep (something)` to avoid the slow on-screen write that slows things down (and minimizing it altogether).

Comment: `dir | findstr File(s)`. Just because it isn't *named* `grep` doesn't mean you can't.

Comment: assuming you have a barebone cmd and no powershell

Comment: this doesn't work well when there are millions of files.

Answer (score 3):

just count lines from the dir /B output (directories included):
`dir /B | find /c /v "~~~"`

for just count files (with no dirs):
`dir /A-D /B | find /c /v "~~~"`

Comment: This returns files and directory count as a total

Answer (score 2):

Found [this](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/count-files-in-a-directory/12308.html) on the net:

```
dir /a-d | find /c ":" > NUMfiles.###
set /p count=<NUMfiles.###
echo %count%
```

I tested and it seems to work.

Comment: “Seems to” is the correct word here. (1) This is off by one in any case, since the `dir` command includes a line with a colon in it which is *not* a file. (2) This relies on the time format to include a colon, which doesn't necessarily have to be so. (3) It relies on the number format *not* including a colon, which also doesn't necessarily have to be so. Besides, going through a file here is unnecessary and won't work if you don't have write access—bad idea.

Comment: How to make it without creating file "NUMfiles.###" ?

Answer (score 2):

Just a caveat for those who might use Trevoke's PowerShell answer above ([Windows command prompt: how to get the count of all files in current directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/110725/windows-command-prompt-how-to-get-the-count-of-all-files-in-current-directory/110742#110742)): by design, echoing the Count property of a collection returned by Get-ChildItem can give misleading results if the value is 1 or 0. This is because the Count property is only available on arrays. If fewer than 2 items are returned by Get-ChildItem, the result is scalar, and .Count returns nothing. To get around this, explicitly cast it into an array, e.g., @(Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts).Count.

For more info, see http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/354672/get-childitem-count-problem-with-one-file or http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/266379-get-childitem-count-not-working-one-file.html.

Answer (score 0):

`dir` returns the number of files and dirs at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

DIr will of course work

Without installing something on the server but having powershell on your workstation you 
could do:

```
(gwmi -computer theserver -query "select *from cim_datafile where path = '\\'").count
```

that command will give you all the files (system and hidden included)
and as previously mentioned if powershell is on the machine you can simply

```
(GCI c:\*.*).count
```

Note that if you do not include the *.* you will get a count of all files and all directories.  You will not include hidden and system files you need to add -force to count them all

Answer (score 0):

If I only needed this once I'd just use dir, otherwise I'd consider rolling my own, probably as a C# app because that's what I would be most familiar with (although VBScript or PowerShell would also be viable).

(By the way - it's not DOS if you're using cmd.exe)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use attrib to get the file count:

```
attrib.exe /s /D *.*|find /c /v "" >> filecount.txt
```

This will create a file called filecount.txt in the current directory with the number of files and folders in the current directory (including the newly created file). You can change the

```
*.*
```

to

```
<full_path>\*.*
```

in order to get the file count of a particular directory. Remove the "/D" option if you don't want to count folders. The "/s" option processes files in all directories in the specified path. So remove it if you only want files in the specified path and don't want to include files in sub folders.

So for example if you want to find out how many files are in your C:\ drive and not any subfolder you would use the command:

```
attrib.exe C:\*.* | find /c /v "" >> filecount.txt
```

Comment: Using files for results is not the smartest idea. What do you do if the current directory is not writable by you?

Comment: @Johannes Use a directory you do have write access to? e.g. pipe the output to C:\MyWritableDir\filecount.txt

Comment: Still unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

I'm doing something similar and this works with any number of files instantly.

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Dir /A | find "File(s)" >tmp

For /F "tokens=1" %%i in (tmp) do set n=%%i

Del tmp

If !n! GEQ 10 echo Too many files in directory.
```

Comment: Why post an useless (and flawed) answer to a 6-year-old question with already lots of (good) anwers?

Comment: @Massimo because I was not satisfied with the answers above and wanted a more elegant solution. Why stand in the way of the pursuit of knowledge which is not limited by time?

Comment: Urgh! The replies look horrible. Edited solution into answer. No need to thank me I love negative rep for helping others :-P

Comment: There's really no reason to use a temp file to hold some output; also, using `find` is not a good idea. See the accepted answer for details.

Comment: @Massimo I answered your question. You owe me an answer to mine. If you can show me how to avoid using the temp file I'd appreciate that. I already read all the answers which is why I posted my own. You are assuming that because an answer is accepted that new answers can't be found. It's not just for the OP but for everyone looking for the same solution.

Comment: @Massimo and if you had read my reply to you you would have seen I said I read the other answers.

Comment: @Massimo and now I am confused because the accepted answer recommends using Find. Found a better answer than the one I posted that I somehow missed before so I accept your -1 for that reason but really you shouldn't harass beginners for trying. I was a few seconds away from reporting you lol

Comment: Have you actually ***read*** the accepted answer? It doesn't use temp files and it doesn't use `find`. It also *warns* about using `find`, because it can fail in multiple ways and should thus be avoided.

Comment: Your answer adds nothing useful to this question (which, again, not only is ***six years old***, but already has a perfectly good answer). Hence the -1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37606/discussion-between-aaron-lowe-and-massimo).

Comment: Moved to dicussion. Plus the answer I thought was better doesn't work if there are no files in the directory. So I'm using my "flawed", "pointless" and "useless" answer as it is the best one.

Comment: Do as you wish. Bye.